# vue and vuex shopping cart quantity update problem?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

[image: Checkout Page]

This is my shopping cart checkout page when I click the **+** button for increasing quantity or click **-** button for decreasing quantity its not working but when I navigate to product page and go back to the checkout page again that time I see quantity was updated. Why realtime DOM not responding or showing me update? Someone please tell me what's going on under the hood and how will I solve this issue. Thanks

Here is my project link
[Shopping Cart (https://codesandbox.io)](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue2-router-vuex-wxs83)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state.cart[productInCartIndex].quantity++;`

Vue2 reactivity is based on object getters and setters. When you assign value directly like this `object[key]` instead of this `object.key`, vue reactivity is not triggered.

If you must do it this way, use Vue.set that overcome this issue. See more here:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html

Comment: Hello, I don't know what is your name? whatever! Many many thanks for your vital guideline. I've read vuejs documentation about reactivity and after 2 days I've achived my aim and finally I got. Thanks once again @Dutch77